# What is the literal meaning of word Tafsir and where from it originates?

Tags: tafseer, arabic, terminology

Tafseer is interpreted as the explanation of Quranic Verses. What is the litral meaning of word tafseer and its origin.Explain on the basis of historical background.

Comment: Please note that this site is not for questions on the Arabic language, unless they are directly relevant to Islamic teachings. The literal meaning, origin and historical background of an Arabic word is likely off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tafseer means explanation. It occurs in the Quran only once. it is in Sura Furqan verse 25

> وَلَا يَأۡتُونَكَ بِمَثَلٍ إِلَّا جِئۡنَٰكَ بِٱلۡحَقِّ وَأَحۡسَنَ
>   **تَفۡسِيرًا**
>
> > And they do not come to you with an argument except that We bring you
> >     the truth and the best **explanation**. Quran 25:33